# Regex to get a substring between < >

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like `" test data \<tag1 attribute1="124" attribut2="abc"\> </tag>test end data"`

I need sub string between `"<tag1" and ">"` as below:

```
"<tag1 attribute1="124" attribut2="abc">"
```

I have implemented below regex code for that:

```
var regex = new Regex("<tag1(.*)>");
var match = regex.Match(result);
var tagContent = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Above did not help, it returned empty string.

Can anyone suggest me the right way of extracting content between `"<tag1" and ">"` using regex?

Comment: Do not parse XML using Regex

Comment: [*turn back now*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/23354); if this is html, use a tool like `HtmlDocument`; if this is xml: use an xml library. This is not a job for regex

Comment: @SouvikGhosh - I guess he means both, a string in `" "` in a `< >`, so bascially he wants to grab the attribute value.

Comment: @RandRandom Yeah I realized after someone edited the post.

Comment: Well the end of that tag is `\>` not `>`, so did you try `<tag1(.*)\\>`?

Comment: <tag1 (.*\")\\>

Comment: The two posts I linked to will solve your current problem, but the right idea is to use appropriate tools to parse mark-up texts.

Comment: He comes...tony the pony

Comment: @Equalsk - I tried both <tag1(.*)\\> and <tag1 (.*\")\\>. None of them helped.